# "Forwarding" an image upload with Java

Tags: java, image, upload

I have a Web Service that receives an image upload by a Multipart POST request. I would like to forward the file to another web service without storing it, as the environment does not have access to a file system, so basically just passing along the information that's being received.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the other webservice resides on the same server use:

```
String url = "<relative path>";
request.getRequestDispatcher(url).forward(request, response);
return;
```

otherwise use:

```
response.sendRedirect(url);
```

Comment: Unfortunately, simply forwarding the request is not an option. I do need the image the POST'ed to the server before, and then just send it somewhere else.

Comment: so start by saving the image - by using a form with enctype="multipart/form-data" property, and after you're done saving the image - forward the request.

Comment: I did something similar - using CXF I was able to receive a byte[] as input, and then use a ByteArrayBody(byte[], filename) to attach it to the outgoing Http Request. The image does not need to be saved for this.

Answer (score 1):

You could always try *chaining* the input and output streams from one to the other, but I suspect you won't get very far with this when there's a hiccup on either side of the connection.

Another option you have, depending on how much memory you have access to, is to save it as a *variable* after you fetch it, and then pass it along to the other webservice. This of course won't work with very large images but it's a starting point.

Comment: The images are going to be rather small, so I might consider that approach. Thanks!